# Keccak on react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, ethereum, keccak

I trying the [`ethereumjs-util`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util) in `react-native` , first `ethUtil.privateToPublic` work fine, then when use `ethUtil.publicToAddress` will getting this error **`TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`** , I trace the error actually come from `Keccak`.

Then I try [Keccak](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/keccak#readme) it self :

```
const createKeccakHash = require('keccak');
console.log(createKeccakHash('keccak256').digest().toString('hex'));
```

also getting the same error **`TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use `js-sha3` I know that it maybe your module doesn't support `React Native.`

```js
keccak256 = require('js-sha3').keccak256;
var bytes = keccak256.digest();
console.log(bytes);
```

Comment: hi, anything different between `js-sha3` and `keccak` ?

Comment: @ImHappy I actually tried both modules. So I am talking about my experience. I don't know why because I didn't go into details.